# I need to reshape my wide table into long format but keeping multiple fields for each record, for example:

Tags: r

```
src   hop1   hop2   hop3    hop4    destination
 A     B      C      NA      NA      NA
 P     Q      R      S       NA      NA
 H     I      J      K       L       M
```

Now I want to melt this table to below format

```
src nn en
 A  B  C
 B  C  C
 P  Q  S
 Q  R  S
 R  S  S
 H  I  M
 I  J  M
 J  K  M
 K  L  M
 L  M  M
```

I have basic understanding of melt and reshape, but not able to visualize how i can leverage those functions for the desired output.

Comment: Can you please explain the process to get from your input to your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to gather all the columns up, grouped by each row. Then look forward to the leading value, and to the last value. So something like this in *dplyr*:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, src, -row) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(nn=lead(src), en=last(src)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(nn)) %>%
  arrange(row) %>%
  select(src, nn, en)

## A tibble: 10 x 3
#   src   nn    en   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     B     C    
# 2 B     C     C    
# 3 P     Q     S    
# 4 Q     R     S    
# 5 R     S     S    
# 6 H     I     M    
# 7 I     J     M    
# 8 J     K     M    
# 9 K     L     M    
#10 L     M     M
```

Or like this in base R:

```
tmp <- na.omit(data.frame(row=seq_len(nrow(dat)), src=unlist(dat), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
tmp$nn <- ave(tmp$src, tmp$row, FUN=function(x) c(tail(x,-1),NA) )
tmp$en <- ave(tmp$src, tmp$row, FUN=function(x) tail(x,1) )
tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp$nn),]
tmp[order(tmp$row), c("src","nn","en")]

#      src nn en
#src1    A  B  C
#hop11   B  C  C
#src2    P  Q  S
#hop12   Q  R  S
#hop22   R  S  S
#src3    H  I  M
#hop13   I  J  M
#hop23   J  K  M
#hop33   K  L  M
#hop43   L  M  M
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="src   hop1   hop2   hop3    hop4    destination
 A     B      C      NA      NA      NA
 P     Q      R      S       NA      NA
 H     I      J      K       L       M", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks a ton, it ll take some time for me to understand how this code works, but if someone can explain it ll be great

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `apply` from `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
    x1 <- na.omit(x)
    data.frame(src = x1[-length(x1)], nn = x1[-1], en = x1[length(x1)])
   }))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   src nn en
#1    A  B  C
#2    B  C  C
#3    P  Q  S
#4    Q  R  S
#5    R  S  S
#6    H  I  M
#7    I  J  M
#8    J  K  M
#9    K  L  M
#10   L  M  M
```

---

Or another option in `base R` would be to use `max.col` to find the last non-NA element, use `rep` to replicate the last non-NA element in each row and create `data.frame`

```
ij <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), max.col(!is.na(dat), "last"))
v1 <- dat[ij]
i1 <- rowSums(!is.na(dat))
src <- na.omit(c(t(replace(dat, ij, NA))))
nn <-  na.omit(c(t(dat)[-1,])) 
data.frame(src ,nn,  en = rep(v1, i1-1 ))
#   src nn en
#1    A  B  C
#2    B  C  C
#3    P  Q  S
#4    Q  R  S
#5    R  S  S
#6    H  I  M
#7    I  J  M
#8    J  K  M
#9    K  L  M
#10   L  M  M
```